# Insert element in a linked list - index doesn't exist

Tags: c, linked-list

I was given a C code sample to insert a new element in a linked list at a given index. But with the original code I get always the error that the index is not correct, and I don't know whether I don't understand the code, or if there is an error in the code.

The *insert* operation is defined as follows:

```
void insert (list *l, int e, int index) {
    int i;
    node *tmp;
    node *prev;
    i=1;
    prev=l->first;
    while (!end(prev) && (i<index-1)) {
        i++;
        prev=prev->next;
    }
    if ( ((i+1) <= index) ) {
        printf("\n Error: index position doesn't exist\n");
    }
    else {
        tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            printf("\n Error: Not enough free memory\n");
        }
        else {
            tmp->e = e;
            if (emptyList(*l)) {
                /* empty list */
                tmp->next=NULL;
                l->first=tmp;
            }
            else {
                if (index == 1) {
                    /* no previous element */
                    tmp->next=l->first;
                    l->first=tmp;
                }
                else {
                    /* standard case */
                    tmp->next=prev->next;
                    prev->next=tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I always get the *index position doesn't exist* error for any index other than 1. And I understand that a valid index should be in the range (1 <= index <= number_elements+1)

If I modify the condition which gives the error as follows:

```
if ( ((i+1) < index) ) {
    printf("\n Error: index position doesn't exist\n");
}
```

Then it works except when the index is the number of elements of the list +2, which results in a segmentation fault.

Is there a way to fix this? I figured a way by using an auxiliar function which counts the number of elements of the list:

```
if ( index > count_elements(l)+1 ) {
    printf("\n Error: index position doesn't exist\n");
}
```

But I would like to know how to solve it using the *i* variable in the *insert* function.

Here is a short version of running code I use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tnode {
    int e;
    struct tnode *next;
} node;

typedef struct {
    node *first;
} list;


int end(node *n)
{
       return (n==NULL);
}

int emptyList (list l)
{
       return(l.first==NULL);
}

void createList(list *l)
{
    l->first=NULL;
}


    void insert (list *l, int e, int index) {
        int i;
        node *tmp;
        node *prev;
        i=1;
        prev=l->first;
        while (!end(prev) && (i<index-1)) {
            i++;
            prev=prev->next;
        }
        if ( ((i+1) <= index) ) {
            printf("\n Error: index position doesn't exist\n");
        }
        else {
            tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                printf("\n Error: Not enough free memory\n");
            }
            else {
                tmp->e = e;
                if (emptyList(*l)) {
                    /* empty list */
                    tmp->next=NULL;
                    l->first=tmp;
                }
                else {
                    if (index == 1) {
                        /* no previous element */
                        tmp->next=l->first;
                        l->first=tmp;
                    }
                    else {
                        /* standard case */
                        tmp->next=prev->next;
                        prev->next=tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    list l;

    createList(&l);

    printf("insert at index 1\n");
    insert(&l, 10, 1);

    printf("insert at index 1\n");
    insert(&l, 20, 1);

    printf("insert at index 2\n");
    insert(&l, 30, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your first condition is “i must be less than index-1” which means if there are enough nodes i will end up being index-1. Then you check if i+1 is less than or equal to index and if it is you show an error. Which will always happen. So one of these conditions is obviously wrong. Use a debugger in these cases to run through your code and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( ((i+1) <= index) )
```

Maybe this is condition you want?

```
if ( ((i+1) <= index) && end(prev))
```